# CXX FLAGS syntax for cmake

Tags: cmake, gcc-warning

I need to pass flags `-Wno-type-limits` and `-Wno-psabi` to cmake. I am trying to pass the arguments as follows at command line :

```
CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-type-limits CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-psabi cmake
```

However it seems the syntax is incorrect. I am still getting errors about -Werror=type-limits in my make command. What is the correct way of passing these flags toghther

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening is only your second `CXXFLAGS` is getting stored:

```
$ CXXFLAGS=-Wno-type-limits CXXFLAGS+=-Wno-psabi eval echo '$CXXFLAGS'
-Wno-psabi
```

Instead, you can set the `CXXFLAGS` variable to contain both flags:

```
CXXFLAGS="-Wno-type-limits -Wno-psabi" cmake
```